# LESS mix-in for nth-child?

Tags: css, less, mixins

I'm trying to make a LESS mixin that will give me this output:

```
.resource:nth-child(8n+1) { clear: left; }
```

I've got this so far:

```
.wrap-every(@n) {
    &:nth-child(@n + "n+1") {  // parse error on this line
        clear: left;
    }
}

.resource {
    .wrap-every(8);
}
```

But it's giving a parse error on the indicated line

> **ParseError: Unrecognised input**

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

### Less >= 1.4

you could do something like this:

```
.wrap-every(@n) {
  &:nth-child(@{n}n + 1) {
        clear: left;
    }
}
```

this should have the desired output. Without any hacks needed.

### in older versins of Less

you can try simple *string interpolation*:

```
.wrap-every(@n) {
    @t: ~":nth-child(@{n}n + 1)";
    &@{t} {
        clear: left;
    }
}
```

and the output *CSS* in both cases should be something like this:

```
.resource:nth-child(8n + 1) {
  clear: left;
}
```

Comment: +1 for including the new syntax of @{n}, because in previous version of less we could just use the @n syntax.

Comment: Using a recent dotless (for .net) and the older version worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: This solved my problem! Just in case someone's searching, I was trying to include `nth-last-child` with a variable inside a mixin, and was getting the error `Missing closing ')'`. Was driving me bananas. `@{variable}` syntax inside `nth-last-child` fixed it!

Comment: what is the syntax for `nth-last-child`? above technique not working for me